# Selenium 2 and JUnit4: How to capture screenshot on exception?

Tags: exception, junit, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I want to capture a screenshot only upon unexpected exception.

Comment: You should post your solution as an actual answer(which you can accept later). Your problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>Note.- This answer could be outdated. The answer is based on Selenium 2.15</sub>

Using [TestWatcher](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) does the trick (the unit test must extend following `BaseTest`):

```java
public abstract class BaseTest {
// ...
protected WebDriver driver;


@Rule
public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void starting(Description desc) {
        LOG.info("Launching browser...");
        driver = Utils.getFirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public void finished(Description desc) {
        LOG.info("Quitting driver...");
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, Description d) {
        LOG.debug("Creating screenshot...");
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(
                OutputType.FILE);
        String scrFilename = "Screenshot.png";
        File outputFile = new File(SCREEN_SHOTS_RESULTS_PATH, scrFilename);
        LOG.info(scrFilename + " screenshot created.");
        try {
            org.​apache.​commons.​io.FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, outputFile);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("Error copying screenshot after exception.", ioe);
        }
    }
};
}
```

---

#### Note

`Utils.getFirefoxDriver()` returns a customized `WebDriver`. Something like:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class Utils {
    // ...
    public static WebDriver getFirefoxDriver() {
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

        // Profile customization. For example:
        // firefoxProfile.addExtension("firebug-1.8.4-fx.xpi");
        // firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion","1.8.4");

        FirefoxBinary firefox = new FirefoxBinary();

        // Firefox customization. For example:
        // firefox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", display);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefox, firefoxProfile);

        // WebDriver customizations. For example:
        // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(SHORT_TIMEOUT_S, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Comment: JUnit has since deprecated TestWatchman in favor of TestWatcher.

Comment: I can't find `Utils.getFirefoxDriver();`. Has this been removed or is this your own implementation? How can I get the correct driver instance?

Comment: @vanto It is my own implementation. I have added a clarification to my answer.

Comment: Cool solution, however, you have to be careful when using a `@After` annotated tearDown method in which you close your selenium driver. The problem is that the TestRule is executed posterior to the `@After` method.

Comment: And the second issue in which I ran: My driver instance was not castable to `TakeScreenshot`. Fortunately, it worked by augmenting the driver with: `WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);` and taking the `augmentedDriver` for casting. Found this solution here: http://rkchunduri.blogspot.de/2011/11/remotewebdriver-cannot-be-cast-to.html

Comment: @rainer198 Thanks for your correction, although I cannot test it now. I'm upvoting you, so your comment comes up to help others. If you post a working updated solution, I'll change the accepted answer... If it's just that edit to make it work, feel free to edit.