# Can Selenium take a screenshot on test failure with JUnit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, junit4, selenium-webdriver

When my test case fails, especially on our build server, I want to take a picture / screenshot of the screen to help me debug what happened later on.  I know how to take a screenshot, but I was hoping for a way in JUnit to call my `takeScreenshot()` method if a test fails, before the browser is closed.

No, I don't want to go edit our bazillions of tests to add a try/catch.  I could maybe, just possibly be talked into an annotation, I suppose.  All of my tests have a common parent class, but I can't think of anything I can do there to solve this.

Ideas?

Comment: In what kind of failure? When it can't click on a element? When it can't find an element immeaditely? When it can't find an element after waiting a little bit? When it can't launch the browser? The way I have done this is have a central method when the browser finds elements, wrap it in a try catch and in the catch, take a screenshot. Whenever I need to find an element, call this. Then this will handle it for you.

Comment: With TestNG you can easly achive that. You only need a listner that takes the screenshot. If you are interested in a TestNG solution I will post my code for that tomorrow.

Comment: Possible dup of: [Selenium 2 and JUnit4: How to capture screenshot on exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7649994/413020)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few quick searches led me to a relevant article, "Grabbing Screenshots of Failed Selenium Tests" by Jason Lee, dated 24 Jan 2012. (Defunct original blogs.steeplesoft.com url: http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2012/grabbing-screenshots-of-failed-selenium-tests.html, now available from [an archive.org mirror dated 7 Mar 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170307174236/http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2012/grabbing-screenshots-of-failed-selenium-tests.html).)

In short, he recommends creating a JUnit4 `Rule` that wraps the test `Statement` in a try/catch block in which he calls:

```
imageFileOutputStream.write(
    ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
```

In the comments, Leukipp links to a similar article ["Performing an action when a test fails"](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/07/08/performing-an-action-when-a-test-fails), by Thomas Sundberg, dated 8 Jul 2012, which offers a very similar @Rule but using `getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)` which is then copied/moved to the intended destination.

Comment: Yes, that's awesome.  I wish I'd seen this earlier.  I've already gone with Tarken's approach.

Comment: I found this searching for a c# way to do it. So for posterity in c# the way to do it is something like `((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenShot().SaveAsFile(@"path\to\file.png" ImageFormat.Png)`

Comment: @bummi Great, thanks! (And thanks Luc for the edit!)

Comment: The following article describes how to use a TestWatcher for taking screenshots: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/07/08/performing-an-action-when-a-test-fails I found it more helpful than the article mentioned by Jeff.

Comment: This article back from 2012 doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @user1053510 I've updated the post with an archive.org link and integrated Leukipp's other blog (which is very similar and still available).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to quickly add this behavior to **ALL** your tests in the run you can use the `RunListener` interface to listen for test failures.

```
public class ScreenshotListener extends RunListener {

    private TakesScreenshot screenshotTaker;

    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
        File file = screenshotTaker.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
        // do something with your file
    }

}
```

Add the listener to your test runner like this...

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(new ScreenshotListener((TakesScreenShots) webDriver));

// then run your test...

Result result = junit.run(Request.classes(FullTestSuite.class));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take a screenshot on test failure, add this class

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.junit.rules.MethodRule;

import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;

import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class ScreenShotOnFailure implements MethodRule {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public ScreenShotOnFailure(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod, final Object o) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    statement.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    captureScreenShot(frameworkMethod.getName());
                    throw t;
                }
            }

            public void captureScreenShot(String fileName) throws IOException {
                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                fileName += UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                File targetFile = new File("./Screenshots/" + fileName + ".png");
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, targetFile);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And Before all tests, you should use this Rule:

```
@Rule
public ScreenShotOnFailure failure = new ScreenShotOnFailure(driver));

@Before
public void before() {
   ...
}
```